# My variable is coming back as undefined in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to challenge myself by creating a program from scratch to help work out errors, etc.

So I did a simple stamp shop which has different values for various books of stamps. I now want to calculate the price per piece after collecting taxes. I have tried to setup an if/elif/else statement to calculate the price per stamp. Here is the code that I have so far.

'''
# what is the price per stamp including taxes

```
    number_of_stamps_purchased = 10

    # calculate government sales taxes on stamps 13%

    sales_tax = 0.13
    # number of stamps in each booklet

    single_stamp = 1
    book_of_five = 5
    book_of_ten = 10
    book_of_fifteen = 15
    book_of_twenty = 20
   
    # pricing chart for each book of stamps
    single = 1.50
    five = 7.00
    ten = 10.00
    fifteen = 14.00
    twenty = 16.00
  
    # price list for customers
    print('''Welcome to my stamp shop!

    Please review our price list:

    Single Stamp $1.50
    Book of 5 Stamps $7.00
    Book of 10 Stamps $10.00
    Book of 15 Stamps $14.00
    Book of 20 Stamps $16.00

    (Does not include sales tax)''')

    # conditions for total price calculation of stamps purchased

    def stamp_cost(price_per_piece):
    if number_of_stamps_purchased <= 4:
    print('''
    Your stamp cost:''',((single * sales_tax / single_stamp) + single) * number_of_stamps_purchased)
      elif number_of_stamps_purchased == 5:
        print('''
    Your stamp cost:''',((five * sales_tax) + five))
      elif number_of_stamps_purchased == 10:
        print('''
    Your stamp cost:''',((ten * sales_tax) + ten))
      elif number_of_stamps_purchased == 15:
        print('''
     Your stamp cost:''',((fifteen * sales_tax) + fifteen))
      elif number_of_stamps_purchased == 20:
        print('''
    Your stamp cost:''',((twenty * sales_tax) + twenty))
      else:
        print('Error')'''

    # calculate the per piece price based on their savings when purchasing a book
    print(total_price / number_of_stamps_purchased)
```

'''

Comment: can you share the full error message/traceback ?

Comment: Please make sure that the code you supply runs as is and allows to reproduce the problem.

Comment: After getting the code running, I find there are a few open points: a) the parameter `price_per_piece` in your function is never used, so you can get rid of it: `def stamp_cost():...`. b) `total_price` is used but never defined (I guess this is the problem you have), so either set a value to `total_price`, or remove that particular line.

Comment: Maybe using global variable in local scope made that kind of error. https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_variables_global.asp -> this will help you

Answer (score 0):

You never declare a variable with the name `total_price`, so when you try and print with `print(total_price / number_of_stamps_purchased)` Python warns you about never defining it. You can fix this by defining a `total_price` before the last line. Perhaps like so:

```
def stamp_cost():  # I have removed the argument as it was unused.
    if number_of_stamps_purchased <= 4:
        total_price = ((single * sales_tax / single_stamp) + single) * number_of_stamps_purchased
        print('''
Your stamp cost:''', total_price)
    # The rest of the function with the same modification
    return total_price

total_price = stamp_cost()
print(total_price / number_of_stamps_purchased)
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like that should work a little better. The main problem as it as been previously pointed is that you never call your fonction `stamp_cost`. So, what you need to do is affect the result of what you are doing with `stamp_cost` to your variable `total_price`.

```
# calculate government sales taxes on stamps 13%

sales_tax = 0.13

# pricing chart for each book of stamps
    
single = 1.50
five = 7.00
ten = 10.00
fifteen = 14.00
twenty = 16.00
    
# number of stamps in each booklet

single_stamp = 1
book_of_five = 5
book_of_ten = 10
book_of_fifteen = 15
book_of_twenty = 20
   
  
# price list for customers
print('''Welcome to my stamp shop!

Please review our price list:

Single Stamp $1.50
Book of 5 Stamps $7.00
Book of 10 Stamps $10.00
Book of 15 Stamps $14.00
Book of 20 Stamps $16.00

(Does not include sales tax)
''')

# conditions for total price calculation of stamps purchased

def stamp_cost():
    if number_of_stamps_purchased <= 4:
        total_price = (single * sales_tax / single_stamp + single) * number_of_stamps_purchased
        print('Your total cost:', total_price)
    elif number_of_stamps_purchased == 5:
        total_price = five * sales_tax + five
        print('Your total cost:',total_price)
    elif number_of_stamps_purchased == 10:
        total_price = ten * sales_tax + ten
        print('Your total cost:', total_price)
    elif number_of_stamps_purchased == 15:
        total_price = fifteen * sales_tax + fifteen
        print('Your total cost:',total_price)
    elif number_of_stamps_purchased == 20:
        total_price = twenty * sales_tax + twenty
        print('Your total cost:',total_price)
    else:
        print('Error')
    return total_price

number_of_stamps_purchased = 10

print('Number of stamp purchase:',number_of_stamps_purchased)
total_price = stamp_cost()
# calculate the per piece price based on their savings when purchasing a book
print('Price per piece:',round(total_price / number_of_stamps_purchased,2))
```